# Reconciliation between two definitions of Jacobi field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations

Let $x:\Sigma^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a CMC (constant mean curvature) immersion of an orientable compact smooth $n$-dimensional manifold $\Sigma$. Denote the Gauss map by $\nu$.

In [Barbosa-do Carmo](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01215045.pdf), a *Jacobi field* is defined to be a normal vector field $\varphi\nu$ where $\varphi:\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function satisfying the following:

1. $\varphi\equiv 0$ on the boundary $\partial\Sigma$.
2. $\displaystyle\int_{\Sigma}\varphi d\mu=0$, where $d\mu$ is the area element in the induced metric.
3. $\varphi$ satisfies 
   \begin{align}
   \Delta\varphi+|A|^2\varphi=0
   \end{align}
   (where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian in the induced metric, and $A$ is the second fundamental form) which was called the *Jacobi equation* in the paper.

This looks quite different from the usual definition of Jacobi field (and Jacobi equation) that we've learnt, which is defined using ***geodesic***. Thus I would like to ask if there is any relation between these two seemingly distinct notions of Jacobi field? Or it just happens to be a mere coincidence that both are named the same?

My gut feeling is that the former is probably the case, since the Jacobi equation in item 3 appears in the *second variation formula* of some functional (e.g. area functional) at a critical point. Thus it seems to be a higher-dimensional analogue of the usual Jacobi equation. But this is just a gut feeling. I'm not sure if this is true, or if there's any detail I've missed.

Any comment or answer are welcomed and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are indeed related as you described. Whenever one has a functional $A$ defined on a space (of mappings) $\mathscr M$, then the second variations (at a critical point $P$) defines the Jacobi operator $\mathscr J$:

$$\mathscr J : T_p\mathscr M \to T_p\mathscr M, \ \ \ \langle \mathscr J X, X\rangle = \frac{d^2}{ds^2}\bigg|_{s=0} A(X_s).$$

and an element in the Kernel of $\mathscr J$ is called a Jacobi field. This terminology is at least used for geodesics, minimal surface, CMC surfaces and harmonic mappings.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any recommendation on the references where such general definition appears? Would like to take a glimpse on the general theory though.